# Determining the output with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I need help understanding some of the outputs of the code below. (This is just a sample question for a midterm, not homework).

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void figure_me_out(int* a, int b, int c, int* d);

 int main(void) {
     int var1 = 1, var2 = 10, var3 = 15, var4 = 20;
     figure_me_out(&var1, var2, var3, &var4);
     printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", var1, var2, var3, var4);
     return 0;
 }

 void figure_me_out(int* a, int b, int c, int* d) {
     c = b;
     b = *d;
     *a = 222;
     *d = 100;
     a = d;
     *a = c;
 }
```

Output

```
 222, 10, 15, 10
```

When I went through the code, I got 10, 10, 15, 100. This was my logic:

c = 10 ---> c was passed by value, so c does not change for printf
b = 20 ---> same reason as above
*a = 222 ---> this dereferences a and gives it the value of 222. Since var a was passed by reference, it changes the original value.
*d = 100 ---> same reason as above

(this part is where I get confused)
a = 100 ---> I'm thinking that since d was changed to 100, that means a is assigned what d equals now, which is 100.
*a = 10 ---> changing the value of a to 10

I know that the function did not alter the original values of b (var2) and c (var3) since they were passed by value but it altered the rest. So I'm confused as to why var1 prints as 222 and var4 prints as 10.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference. It is strictly pass-by-value. Pointers are no references, they are first-class types like e.g. `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple I think, Lets go step by step:

```
void figure_me_out(int* a, int b, int c, int* d) 
{
 c = b;    // c = 10
 b = *d;   // b = 20
 *a = 222; // *a = 222 : Value at address a is changed to 222
 *d = 100; // *d = 100 : Value at address d is changed to 100
 a = d;    // a = d: Change address of local pointer variable a to d. 
 *a = c;   // Changing value of address a which is same as address d to 10
}
```

In step 3 you have changed original value at address a which you have passed from main function. 
In step 5 you are changing passed address from main to local variable **a** in function. After doing a = d, local variable having address is changed to address of d. Now anything you do with this address will get effected at address location of **d**
In step 6 you have changed the value of d to 10.

So final answer coming is 222, 10, 15, 10

Comment: Your explanations really helped! The a = d is what confused me, but now I understand, so thank you for your help.

Comment: `a = d` changes the value of the local pointer variable, not its address. Variables cannot have their address changed.  The value of a pointer is the address of another object, *that* is the address changed. (Which again does not change the address of any object, it changes where the pointer points)

Answer (score 0):

1. `b` and `c` are not changed as you say
2. `a` from `main` is changed at `*a = 222`
3. Tricky part: `a = d;` means that `a` now points to the location of `d` variable in `main()` . The following `*a = c` puts `10` to the object pointed to by `a` (and by `d` earlier). Meaning that `d` it`main()` gets `10`

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you. see the below C code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void figure_me_out(int* a, int b, int c, int* d);

int main(void) 
{
    int var1 = 1, var2 = 10, var3 = 15, var4 = 20;
    figure_me_out(&var1, var2, var3, &var4);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", var1, var2, var3, var4);
    return 0;
}

void figure_me_out(int* a, int b, int c, int* d) 
{
    c = b;      // Explanation: c is overidden by b, that means 10 so c is 10 now
    b = *d;     // Explanation: b is 20
    *a = 222;   // Explanation: var1 value modified and it is set 222 (Called by ref.)
    *d = 100;   // Explanation: var4 value modified and it is set 100 (Called by ref.)
    a = d;      // Explanation: integer pointer a stored address of the var4
    *a = c;     // Explanation: 10 assigned to var4 (Because c already modified in first line of the this function)

    //Finally you will get: 222 10 15 10
}
```